# Android ffmpgeg - Nothing happens

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, binary

for my current project I compiled myself ffmpeg together with the x264 libary, following [this](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/07/30/cross-compiling-ffmpeg-with-x264-for-android/)

tutorial. I already saw many questions regarding this topic, but none of the really helped me. Before that I tried many other things which resulted in many .so files (libavcodec etc.). Since I don't have the time (yet) to work with JNI in depth I wanted to rely to the command line, which the tutorial above seemed to provide. But here comes the problem: the generated file doesn't do anything (no output and no error messages) when I run it with Process on my Android device. I've come to the conclusion, that the generated file still is a .so file (it is readable with readelf). So far I haven't found a solution to run ffmpeg on my device with the command-line. Do you know if I did something wrong?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this some time ago but for anyone having problems, here is the solution:

- I tried [this](https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android/) which seemed to create ffmpeg binary executables for x86, armeabi-v7a and armeabi-v7a-neon
- Next I copied them on my phone and set the file's permission to 775 with chmod but it wasn't executable. It turns out that no file on the external storage can be executable. After copying it to the internal storage - /data/local/tmp for instance - and setting the permissions it was executable and worked